# What are the possible values of "SessionCase " tags in InitialFilterCriteria.?

Tags: sip, ims

What are the possible values of "**SessionCase**" tags ( `<SessionCase>?</SessionCase>` ) in "**InitialFilterCriteria**" ?

Example of **IFC** (**InitialFilterCriteria**) :

```
       <InitialFilterCriteria>\n"
           <Priority>3</Priority>\n"
            <TriggerPoint>\n"
                <ConditionTypeCNF>1</ConditionTypeCNF>\n"
               <SPT>\n"
                  <ConditionNegated>0</ConditionNegated>\n"
                  <Group>0</Group>\n"
                  <Group>1</Group>\n"
                  <SessionCase>?</SessionCase>\n"
                </SPT>\n"
            </TriggerPoint>\n"
             <ApplicationServer>\n"
               <ServerName>sip:as3.number.com</ServerName>\n"
               <DefaultHandling>0</DefaultHandling>\n"
              </ApplicationServer>\n"
       </InitialFilterCriteria>\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SessionCase is defined in the 3GPP standard [29228](http://www.qtc.jp/3GPP/Specs/29228-800.pdf):

> 0 (ORIGINATING_SESSION)
>
> 1 (TERMINATING_REGISTERED)
>
> 2 (TERMINATING_UNREGISTERED)
>
> 3 (ORIGINATING_UNREGISTERED)

So the possible values are digits 0, 1, 2 and 3.